# Deprecating a variable in an external library @interface

Tags: java, annotations

Let's say I have an external library implemented into my project, and an annotation interface I'd like to use in it, namely, `FindBy`:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface FindBy {
  String id() default "";

  String name() default "";
}
```

And let's say I want to `@Deprecate` the `String name()` variable.

As this is an external library, I can not go into the interface and simply deprecate it. Extending it, implementing it, or trying to override it hasn't proven fruitful either.

What is the best practice for deprecating this one variable in the external interface?

Comment: Why do you want to deprecate something in an external library for which you don't control the source code (I assumed you don't)? Is this because you do not want to allow the use of the `name` attribute?

Comment: @Laf Yep, that's correct. We want the other parts of this interface, and the interface is used in other parts of the library, which we depend on. So, in our organization, we have decided to deprecate this one variable as to discourage others from using it. For what it's worth, the `FindBy` annotation has many other possible fields than just `id` or `name`, omitted from the question for brevity.

Comment: @jagdpanzer btw, if you need other clarifications, or if you just want to discuss about this, just le me know and we can start a chat.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Java-way of doing this. At least, not if you want to avoid re-packaging the library.
You can, however, leverage the IDE. For example, using IntelliJ IDEA, you can use *External annotations*.

What that means is an `annotation.xml` file is maintained, per package, to contain all the wanted annotations on classes, methods, fields, etc.

After enabling the [External annotation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/external-annotations.html) feature, navigate to your `FindBy` annotation, then, over the target method, open the *quick action* popup

[image]

And choose "*Annotate method ...*". Another popup will appear

[image]

Choose *java.lang.Deprecated*.
At this point, an `annotation.xml` file has been created, with a content similar to

```
<root>
    <item name='com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize java.lang.Class&lt;? extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer&gt; using()'>
        <annotation name='java.lang.Deprecated' />
    </item>
</root>
```

My example is done on the Jackson `JsonSerialize#using` annotation's field.
On the usages, you'll now see it as striked/deprecated

[image]

You can now `git add` and `git push` these files, and everyone on your team will see the field's deprecation.

---

Eclipse has a similar feature, you might be able to leverage it.
See [here](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_external_null_annotations.htm). I never tried as I don't use Eclipse anymore.